# Why Binary Tree is called by that name (Binary)?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

can anyone please explain why *Binary tree* is called *Binary* ?

Comment: Is it so difficult to try the search engine?.... a binary tree is a tree data structure in which each node has at most **two** children, which are referred to as the **left** child and the **right** child

Comment: @B001 , no it's not but when you ask your question you get new answers, or another way of explanation. Regardless of what the question is. Thanks anyway for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Definition Says:
A tree whose elements have at most 2 children is called a binary tree. Since each element in a binary tree can have only 2 children, we typically name them the left and right child.

Answer (score 3):

A binary tree is called binary since each node has at most TWO children. At first glance, the name might be confusing (You might think that it can only store 1's or 0's or something like that). But in the end, it's just a name that stuck since most computer scientist/programmers associate the term "binary" with "at most two distinct values".

In a binary tree, the "two distinct values", are the left and the right node that each node can refer to. You could see it as "node 0" and "node 1", and maybe the name becomes more intuitive?

See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) for further information.